# amp-script: innerHTML renders ampersand-escaped sequences as they are

Tags: amp-html

Here is a minimal example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ampdevmode ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
 </head>
<body data-ampdevmode>
  <amp-script layout="fixed-height" height="800px" script="hello-world">
    <span id="a"></span>
  </amp-script> 
  <script id="hello-world" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
      document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "&lt;&amp;"
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This example just sets the `innerHTML` of the test-span to `&lt;&amp;` and I would expect to get "<&" in the browser window.

However, the browser renders `&lt;&amp;`.

Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: what happens if you use hex: `&#x003C;` and `&#x0026;`

Comment: Doesn’t change anything. Btw it’s a known bug

Comment: copy that - just saw your issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and solutions are not known. See:

- https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/issues/613
- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/27153